# Java: Binary Tree, why root variable outside of TreeNode class?

Tags: java

```
public class BinaryTree {

    private TreeNode root;

    private class TreeNode {
        private TreeNode left;
        private TreeNode right;
        private int data;
        
        public TreeNode(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
```

When binary tree is created, why root is not inside the TreeNode private class, but outside of the method? Thanks

Comment: How else would the `BinaryTree` have any `TreeNode` in it at all?  Try implementing any method in `BinaryTree` without that `root` field.

Comment: Your code is probably incomplete.  I suspect your "final" BinaryTree will probably have a constructor, and methods like "insert()", "delete()" and "find()".  To answer your question, a "BinaryTree" object "[has-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-)" list of "TreeNodes".  Which must be accessed via the "root" member.

Comment: @paulsm4 it *is* incomplete: The indentation was incorrect - the class definition was chopped off after the inner TreeNode class definition.

Comment: @Bohemian: thank you.  Your edit definitely "improved" things :)  But BinaryTree still needs a lot more functionality before it can be considered "useful".  And your reply is exactly what I was trying to say in my comment: just shorter, and clearer ;) Good job!

Comment: thank you for all your answers, now it is clear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BinaryTree` is *made* of `TreeNodes`, and *has* a `TreeNode` as its root, but is not *itself* a `TreeNode`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public final class BinaryTree {

    private TreeNode root;

    private static final class TreeNode {
        private final int data;
        private TreeNode left;
        private TreeNode right;
        
        public TreeNode(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
```

The root node is just the same node as any other with only one difference: the root node does not have a parent.